# Style of unit tests with pytest - Functional or like class that is tested

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I was having a conversation with a colleague on whether unit tests should reflect the class structure of the class that is being tested or whether they should rather be of more functional form.
Suppose I have the following classes

```py
# impl.py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Process(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def forward(self, x):
        return x

class ProcessMultiply(Process):
    def __init__(self, factor):
        super().__init__()
        self._factor = factor

    def forward(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x * self._factor


class ProcessPower(Process):
    def __init__(self, power):
        super().__init__()
        self._power = power

    def forward(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x ** self._power
```

option A) test structure reflects class structure

```py
class TestProcess(ABC):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def processor(self):
        class _DummyProcess(Process):
            def process(self, x):
                return super().process(x)

    def test_process(self, processor):
        x = 5
        out = processor.process(x)
        assert out is x


class TestProcessMultiply(TestProcess):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def processor(self):
        return ProcessMultiply(2)

    def test_process(self, processor):
        super().test_process(processor)

        assert processor.process(5) == 10

class TestProcessPower(TestProcess):
    @pytest.fixture()
    def processor(self):
        return ProcessPower(3)

    def test_process(self, processor):
        super().test_process(processor)

        assert processor.process(2) == 8
```

option B) functional structure

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("processor", [
    ProcessMultiply(1),
    ProcessPower(1)
])
def test_same_type(processor):
    x = 5
    assert isinstance(processor.process(x), int)


def test_multiply():
    p = ProcessMultiply(5)
    assert p.process(2) == 10

def test_power():
    p = ProcessMultiply(3)
    assert p.process(2) == 8
```

Do you have thoughts on this? Is pattern A used at all?

Comment: What do you think are the pros and cons of A and B from your perspective other then some abstract concept? IMHO B is much shorter and concise, i.e. much easier to maintain.

Comment: @dosas I think one beauty of option A is that you can package your code and people that extend it can subclass your tests for their extensions without the need to copy it

Comment: Talking of beauty is highly subjective ;) But why do you think code can only be extended if it can be subclassed? Option B can also be very easily extended. Also why would you package tests?